# Save Changed CSS properties in Cookie?

Tags: css, asp.net

I am working with an ASPX page using CSS to locate DIV properties, these DIV properties can be changed on the page but when I go to print the properties, they are not pushed to the printer.  Is there a way to locally change CSS properties, save them and push them to a server-side ASP page?

I know I could use a DB solution, but that is really not feasible.  Is it possible to save the CSS properties to a local cookie, and reload the page with the cookie properties?  I seem to remember that we use to be able to load variables from cookies directly into a page, but it's been a while...

Comment: sure you can with javascript!

Answer (score 0):

```
document.cookie = "myCustomCss=blah";
```

and for reading

```
var x = document.cookie;
```

[a good explanation is available on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

be careful using cookies for a lot of data or sensitive data, for that you'd probably want to move to using a database.

Comment: I am not saving any sensitive data, only locations of textbox's, and it's only 4 boxes, so at the most it would be 8 variables.  And yeah, I thought about using a database which may still be the best solution in the long run...  The only problem with using cookies is that if the user clears their cache, it's gone.  Maybe saving a local text file?  Hmm...

Comment: Yeah, you can save in a text file and read in for more permanent data.

Answer (score 0):

Presently I am using a pop-up window to edit the CSS properties like this;

```html
<div id="adjDate">
               <a href="#" onclick="SelectName('check-1-date-box')">H</a>
               <br />
               <a href="#" onclick="SelectName('check-1-date-boxV')">V</a>
           </div>
```

The CSS is like this;

```html
   div#adjDate {
        left: 110px;
        top: 1px;
        color: red;
    }
```

I am thinking using CSS variables might be a viable solution, but the JS might be something worth looking into.